# .NET: Strongly-typed HTML "id" attribute

Tags: html, .net

Is there any object in the .NET framework that will sanitize a string so that it is safe to use as the "id" attribute value for an HTML tag?

Comment: Are you planning on allowing end users to add id tags to your HTML?  WTF?

Answer (score 1):

System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() is the closest thing I can think of.

Comment: What if the string starts with a digit?

Comment: I hadn't looked at the spec until just now, but it is a lot more restrictive than what most browsers actually allow for an id attribute:  'ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").'  Making sure it follows that wouldn't be too hard, but you would want to verify that it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of. You could look at the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/types.html#type-name) for allowed characters and implement it. Note that this might me more difficult because you need to make sure that the identifier is unique within the HTML document.